# SQLAlchemy hybrid_property order_by using text

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given the following Model

```py
class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    name = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.age = 0

    @hybrid_property
    def is_configured(self):
        return self.name != '' and self.age > 0
```

Is it possible to construct a query using order_by on `is_configured` hybrid_property using `sqlalchemy.text`?

If we use the ORM to order_by it works

```py
result = Person.query.filter(or_(*some_filters)).order_by(Person.is_configured).all()
```

Using `sqlalchemy.text` results in SQL error stating no column `persons.is_configured`

```py
result = Person.query.filter(or_(*some_filters)).order_by(text('persons.is_configured asc')).all()
```

**UPDATE 2021-07-16**
Some background on why this question was opened: We have a template that renders a table for user accounts where some of the columns are fields on related tables. Clicking the header of a column will sort by the column, sending request to the server with `table_name.column` to order_by. We have one case where the column is a property. We'd like to make this a hybrid_property so we can query and order by it. We could make this work by mapping the text to the ORM, but if there is a way to make it work with the text that the view provides that would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. The `TextClause` is pure SQL and executed against the database. As the hybrid property is an ORM object the database doesn’t know anything about this.

P.s.: There are a few ways to achieve what you want but maybe elaborate a bit more about what you are trying to achieve